# Python Version Specific Code

Tags: python, pygame

I am using Python 3.4.1 and am wondering how I can make my code backwards compatible with python 3.3.*

I am wondering if I could use the following structure;

```
import sys

ver = sys.version_info[0]

if ver == 341* 

INSERT CODE HERE

elif ver = 3.3

more code
```

*I believe that is how you declare python 3.4.1 (if it isn't please correct me.)

The reason I want to do this is because some Pygame methods have had their name changed between versions.

Comment: If you're doing this because pygame's API changed, I think you should check pygame's version, not python's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the mebmers of  [`sys.version_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.version_info) if you want to base your code on the Python version:

```
sys.version_info.major
sys.version_info.minor
sys.version_info.micro
```

Use these members like this:

```
if sys.version_info.major == 3 and sys.version_info.minor == 4:
    print("I like Python 3.4")
```

pygame has [a similar structure](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#module-pygame.version):

```
pygame.version.vernum
```

> tupled integers of the version: vernum = (1, 5, 3)